# Restructure Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| play_id | position | frame | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A_1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | A_2 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | B_1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | A_1 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | A_2 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | B_1 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | A_1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | B_1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | B_2 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | A_1 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | B_1 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | B_2 | 2 | 0.1 | 0.1 |

And I want to reformat to (Multi-Index columns):

| position | A_1 | A_1 | A_1 | A_1 | A_2 | A_2 | A_2 | A_2 | B_1 | B_1 | B_1 | B_1 | B_2 | B_2 | B_2 | B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **coord** | x | x | y | y | x | x | y | y | x | x | y | y | x | x | y | y |
| **frame** | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| **play_id** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **1** | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| **2** | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |

**Importantly**, note that not all positions exist for all play_ids. This will result in some cells being empty.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `sort_values()` so index is in order you want
- `set_index()` existing columns
- `sick()` the **coords**
- name everything
- `unstack()` to get multi-index columns

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""play_id position    frame   x   y
1   A_1 1   0.1 0.1
1   A_2 1   0.1 0.1
1   B_1 1   0.1 0.1
1   A_1 2   0.1 0.1
1   A_2 2   0.1 0.1
1   B_1 2   0.1 0.1
2   A_1 1   0.1 0.1
2   B_1 1   0.1 0.1
2   B_2 1   0.1 0.1
2   A_1 2   0.1 0.1
2   B_1 2   0.1 0.1
2   B_2 2   0.1 0.1"""), sep="\t")

df = df.sort_values(["position","frame","play_id"]).set_index(["position","frame","play_id"]).stack()
df.reindex(df.index.set_names(["position","frame","play_id","coord"])).unstack([0,1,3])
```

#### output

```
position  A_1                 A_2                 B_1                 B_2               
frame       1         2         1         2         1         2         1         2     
coord       x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y    x    y
play_id                                                                                 
1         0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2         0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
```